# How to install and get RAID 0 to work on Rocky Linux 8.7 using AMD controller

Tags: linux, boot, devices, raid, bios

Running this command I can see the RAID controllers for my motherboard in Rocky Linux 8.7

```
[root@richardserver ~]# lspci -nn|grep RAID
03:00.1 RAID bus controller [0104]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43bd] (rev 02)
2d:00.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:7916] (rev 51)
```

I am not sure what to do so that I can see my RAID 0 sata disks/devices on Rocky Linux 8.7. 
I configured and created a RAID0 array of 3 sata disks in the BIOS, no problem. 
I just need to be able to see the devices in Linux. For that to happen, I suppose I need to download and install the right driver. 
The RAID controller info is above.

Does anyone know what I should do, knowing the type of controllers and Linux system?

Comment: If you successfully created a RAID array using the console of onboard controller, then add the output of `df -lh` to the question. Most of the time, the Linux modules/drives will work without needing anything else.